# How to access to a custom component properties by name?

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, vb.net-2010

I have a custom component with several checkboxes and a textbox inside; also have a property/variable that I called "seconds" to store the time.

This customized control is added several times to a TabPage that is inside(nested) another two TabPages at running time.

Every one of this controls have sequential names that are assigned when their are created at running time.

TimerCtrl1

TimerCtrl2

TimerCtrl3

etc...

Now I want to set those checkboxes, the text inside the textbox and the variable seconds by name to load a profile from a file that have the name and properties of every control.

I can change another controls like textboxes that was created at design time with the following code

```
Dim TxtIndex = ProgTab.Controls.Find(Values(0), True)
If TxtIndex.Length > 0 Then
   TxtIndex(0).Text = Values(1) 'Value to TextBox
End If
```

But I'm not able to access to the properties of my own customized control in the same way.

I try to do:

```
 Dim TimerIndex = ProgTab.Controls.Find(Values(0), True)
 If TimerIndex.Length > 0 Then
    TimerIndex(0).seconds = Values(1) 'Syntax ERROR
 End If
```

Any idea about how to solve this?

Comment: By 'customized control' do you mean a User Control?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I do.

Comment: The point of them is to encapsulate some functionality as a unit.  Since you wrote it, add a method or property to tell it to do whatever

Comment: They already have a property called "seconds" and I'm not able to access them by the name of the user control since they not exist at design time. So I'm trying to access them by name.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were trying to drill into the child controls.  When you create them at run time, store the reference to them ("name") in a List or Array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TimerIndex` will be an array of controls (`Control()`). You need to cast the one(s) you access to your specific control if you want to access the property.

```
DirectCast(TimerIndex(0), <user control type name here>).seconds = Values(1)
```

For example:

```
DirectCast(TimerIndex(0), TimerUserControl).seconds = Values(1)
```

- Here, `TimerUserControl` is the generic name of my custom user control.

Read more about `DirectCast` on the [**MSDN documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/directcast-operator).

Comment: @E_Blue : Glad I could help! Good luck!